# Letting users create their own products in Drupal Commerce

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce, drupal-rules

I have Drupal Commerce all set up but I need to allow users to add their own products (like on eBay).

I've created an EntityForm type with all the relevant fields, and have set it up to create an entity (of type Commerce Product) on submission.

The trouble is the custom fields for that product type are not available to submit information to.

Is there any way of making those custom fields available?

Thanks in advance!
Jeremy